# Slicing "bug" in class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, sonarqube

Suppose I have two classes like

```
class Position {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
}

class POI : public Position {
    std::string name;
    // ... many more
}
```

Now I want to make (and modify) a copy of a POI and pass it to a function which only needs
Positions. In order to save copying efforts I do the following:

```
POI poi;

Position pos(poi);
pos.x += 1.;
function(pos);
```

If I let [sonar](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarcloud/) analyze code like this it flags this as a blocker bug `Use pointer or reference to avoid slicing` because of the slicing that occurs when constructing the `pos`, [see here](https://sonarcloud.io/project/issues?issues=AYG4fUR_r_UO8E7QZX4_&open=AYG4fUR_r_UO8E7QZX4_&id=org.eclipse.sumo). I think, I understand what slicing is and I am doing it here fully intentionally and in my opinion the code makes this more than clear. But I am unsure because of the severity sonar assigns to the issue and the proposed solution of using references or pointers (I am not sure how this could help here). So am I missing something obvious here? Should I just ignore this or is there some alternative code which would make sonar and me happier?

I know that this may very well be an oversensitive sonar so please tell me if you think that's the reason. I tried making a copy but I don't think this is the solution in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Slicing is almost always a bug so i imagine that's why it's flagged as an error in your analyser, if you're sure you want slicing just ignore the error

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59867852 (`Position pos{ poi.x + 1., poi.y }` would work. `Position pos(static_cast<const Position&>(poi));` might also silence the analyzer)

Comment: Or solve the whole issue by aggregating a Position into POI? Not everything has to be solved by inheritance ;) If some kind of runtime polymorphism is needed somewhere else both classes could still implement a position interface. (And having a position interface is good for unit testing too)

Comment: @Artyer Thank you for the reference. Yes that is the same problem. Looking at similar warnings https://shorturl.at/aghnU I don't think casting will help. And for the explicit parameter solution. Yes, in this small example that will help but I do not want to do this if I have 10 members in the base class